# How to format an RDSDataService batchExecuteStatement for an update query with parameters?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I'm using the `RDSDataService.batchExecuteStatement` to update records in a postgres database. I'm struggling with understanding how the `query` parameter should be formatted for an update query.

The insert query is very straight forward and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.calling.cli.batch-execute-statement) shows this formatted as

`insert into mytable values (:id, :val)`

With a full request looking like

```
aws rds-data batch-execute-statement --resource-arn "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:mydbcluster" \
--database "mydb" --secret-arn "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:mysecret" \
--sql "insert into mytable values (:id, :val)" \
--parameter-sets "[[{\"name\": \"id\", \"value\": {\"longValue\": 1}},{\"name\": \"val\", \"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"ValueOne\"}}],
[{\"name\": \"id\", \"value\": {\"longValue\": 2}},{\"name\": \"val\", \"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"ValueTwo\"}}],
[{\"name\": \"id\", \"value\": {\"longValue\": 3}},{\"name\": \"val\", \"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"ValueThree\"}}]]"
```

How would an update query look like? Would it just be the following?

`update mytable set :id, set :val`